# compareTo() is not working the way I want

Tags: java, arrays, string, compareto

I'm writing a program and I am stuck on a part where I have to change the ending number of some strings in my first array with my "flight900" file. The first array is already sorted by flight number and each individual has -1 bags. I am using a binary search algorithm to search for the flight900 names in my array, to match them with a string value.
I believe something is wrong in my if-else chain. The if condition is never satisfied. I can't find a way to fix it. Here is my binary search algorithm.

```
public class binarySort 
{
    public static void binary(String[] array, String value, String array2[])
    {

        //Initializing
        int middle, first=0, last=67, position=-1, counter=-1;
        int result=0,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
        boolean found = false;

        //binary search
        while((!found) && (first<=last))
        {
            middle = ((first + last)/2);

            //These are STRINGS to get the first name from the flight900 list
            String str0 = array[middle].substring(6,9);
            String str1 = array[middle].substring(6,10);
            String str2 = array[middle].substring(6,11);
            String str3 = array[middle].substring(6,12);
            String str4 = array[middle].substring(6,13);

            int answer0=0, answer1=0, answer2=0, answer3=0, answer4=0;

            //THESE ARE INTEGERS
            //compareTo(); returns 0 if both values are equal, a positive number of the first is bigger,
            //and a negative number of the first is smaller
            answer0 = str0.compareTo(value);
            answer1 = str1.compareTo(value);
            answer2 = str2.compareTo(value);
            answer3 = str3.compareTo(value);
            answer4 = str4.compareTo(value);
            counter++;

            /*I believe something is wrong in this if-else chain.*/
            if((answer0==0)||(answer1==0)||(answer2==0)||(answer3==0)||(answer4==0))
            {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
                array[position] = array2[counter];

                result = str0.compareTo(value);
            }
            else if((result >= 0)||(a >= 0)||(b >= 0)||(c >= 0)||(d >= 0))
            {
                last = (middle -1);
            }
            else
            {
                first = (middle + 1);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my tester class. Everything seems to work in the tester class, it's just the binary section that does not work. I decided to do the binary search in another class because it started getting unorganized.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class airplane
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String FileName = "Reservationrecords.txt";//FileName is the text file name
        String line;                               //line is the line I read
        String[] allPassengers = new String[67];   //Store "line" in this array to make the list of passengers
        String noOfCheckInBaggage= "-1";           //Everyone starts at -1 bags

        //Try to read the file and put it into "allPassengers" array
        //If can't read file, prints out error
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); //Reads files name
            for(int i=0; i<67; i++)
            {
                    allPassengers[i] = input.readLine();                         //Populates the array
                    allPassengers[i] += noOfCheckInBaggage;                      //Adds "-1" at the end of the element
            }
            input.close();                                                       //You open a file, read a file, then you must close the file
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                System.out.println("Error while reading the file: " + e.getMessage()); //Prints out the error message
        }


        //This section sorts the "allPassengers" array
        int result;                 //Holds -1 or 0
        int minIndex;               //Minimum low value
        String temp;                //Holds a temporary String which is used for swapping
        String minValue;            //Holds the smallest String

        //Insertion sort algorithm for sorting Strings.
        for(int startScan = 0; startScan < allPassengers.length-1; startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            minValue = allPassengers[minIndex];

            //For-loop to sort the array
            for(int index = startScan + 1; index < allPassengers.length; index++)
            {
                result = allPassengers[index].compareTo(minValue);
                if(result < 0)
                {

                    minValue = allPassengers[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }

            //Swap function
            {
                temp = allPassengers[minIndex];
                allPassengers[minIndex] = allPassengers[startScan];
                allPassengers[startScan] = temp;
            }
        }

        String[] flight900 = new String[14];

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("flight900.txt")); //Reads files name
            for(int i=0; i<14; i++)
            {
                flight900[i] = input.readLine();                     //Populates the array
            }
            input.close();                                           //You open a file, read a file, then you must close the file
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                System.out.println("Error while reading the file: " + e.getMessage()); //Prints out the error message
        }

        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Barnett", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Berndt", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Carroll", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Chen", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Vijay", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Chu", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Zheng", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Costello", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Cusumano", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Dougherty", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Dyer", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Eppinger", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Fernandez", flight900);
        binarySort.binary(allPassengers, "Frank", flight900);


        for(int index=0; index<67; index++)
        {
            System.out.println(allPassengers[index]);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my original file that I read to my first array.

```
    AZ495   Malone, Thomas  A1213878    Scorpius
    AZ386   Granja, Joao    A4567897    Canis   
    AZ531   EL Miligi, Haytham  C3947390    Canis   Green peace activist
    AZ900   Franck, Travis  C6755437    Canis   IBN chief researcher
    AZ531   Dhanjal, Surinder   C9219437    Canis   
    AZ495   Mende, Paul D1219097    Cancer  
    AZ386   Hadzima, Joseph D3333123    Virgo   
    AZ874   Francesco, Monticone    D6544678    Eridanus    
    AZ900   Cusumano, Michael   E4543409    Eridanus    
    AZ874   Zhuoran, Zhao   E6577779    Crux    
    AZ531   Barwreck, Obama E6666666 EridanusHead of international spy ring
    AZ531   Misseille, Obama    E6666667 Eridanus Advisor of Barwreck         Obama
    AZ874   Akinc, Bridget  F5456776    Virgo   
    AZ386   Jay, Jason  F5459908    Draco   
    AZ874   Asquith, Paul   F5676655    Aquarius    
    AZ495   Nachtrieb, Robert   F7878333    Leo 
    AZ900   Berndt, Ernst   G5643211    Taurus  
    AZ900   Carroll, John   G5656789    Cepheus 
    AZ531   Cummer, Rick    H3947399    Leo 
    AZ874   Sarfraz, Khurshid   I8767890    Leo 
    AZ386   Bill, Gate  I8978999    Taurus  
    AZ874   Zheng, Wang     J8767765    Eridanus    
    AZ874   Vijay, Garg     K7686546    Capricornus 
    AZ495   Bent, Bernanke  K8888909    Taurus  Inventor of Hot Money Theory
    AZ900   Fernandez, Roberto  L7077765    Leo 
    AZ531   O'Neil, Kevin   L8495849    Virgo   
    AZ531   Alexis, Kwasinski   L9875676    Corona  CEO of Koyota Motor
    AZ531   Babinchuk, Wayne    N9847293    Cancer  
    AZ531   Alan, Bovik O5646324    Draco   
    AZ386   Isaacs, William O8796234    Cepheus 
    AZ900   Costello, Anna  P7878665    Eridanus    
    AZ495   Gregory, Nathaniel  P8796543    Eridanus    
    AZ495   Kritzman, Mark  P9090888    Eridanus    
    AZ874   Ackerman, Joshua    P9809777    Virgo   
    AZ874   Andreas, Gerstlauer P9868568    Cepheus 
    AZ386   Kellogg, Suzuki Q1113133    Corona  Founder of Sonny
    AZ874   Jeff, Andrews   Q2123443    Cancer  United Nation negotiator
    AZ495   Klein, Janice   Q3773331    Cepheus 
    AZ495   Kogan, Leonid   Q7777077    Capricornus 
    AZ531   Lee, Mahnhoon   Q9487400    Taurus  
    AZ900   Chu, Zen    R2000098    Cepheus 
    AZ900   Vijay, Garg R6567123    Corona  
    AZ531   Park, Andrew    S4957459    Aquarius    
    AZ874   Sarfraz, Khurshid   S5654678    Canis   
    AZ531   Sharma, Mridula S7654566    Taurus  Queen of Ingland
    AZ874   Deji, Akinwande S7678769    Canis   
    AZ495   Little, John    S7878653    Crux    
    AZ531   Rahman, Musfiq  S8765567    Corvus  
    AZ386   Hynes, Tod  T2323111    Taurus  
    AZ900   Eppinger, Steven    T2343111    Cancer  
    AZ386   Jackie, Stewart T7773123    Corvus  
    AZ874   Andrea, Alu T7777656    Taurus  
    AZ900   Dyer, Barbara   T8888765    Crux    
    AZ900   Zheng, Wang U1321254    Capricornus 
    AZ531   Kwiatkowska, Mila   U3845738    Virgo   
    AZ386   Michael, Schumacher U5454231    Aquarius    
    AZ900   Barnett, Arnold U7678765    Corvus  
    AZ386   Homer, Jack U8897529    Virgo   
    AZ874   Bei, Yu U8978999    Scorpius    
    AZ900   Dougherty, Jim  W1232121    Scorpius    
    AZ531   Mikhail, Belkin     W9876661    Cepheus 
    AZ495   Roberts, Edward X3434222    Virgo   
    AZ495   Reagans, Ray    X6321235    Canis   
    AZ531   Ahmed, Faheem   X6836493    Crux    
    AZ531   A, Mohd X9878038    Scorpius    
    AZ495   O'Shea, Rory    Y1212332    Canis   
    AZ900   Chen, Elaine    Y7876780    Draco   Nobel prize (Beauty)
```

And just incase, here is my flight900 text file that I want to change the end numbers to.

```
    Barnett, Arnold U7678765    0
    Berndt, Ernst   G5643211    1
    Carroll, John   G5656789    1
    Chen, Elaine    Y7876780    1
    Vijay, Garg R6567123    -1
    Chu, Zen    R2000098    2
    Zheng, Wang U1321254    0
    Costello, Anna  P7878665    1
    Cusumano, Michael   E4543409    1
    Dougherty, Jim  W1232121    -1
    Dyer, Barbara   T8888765    2
    Eppinger, Steven    T2343111    -1
    Fernandez, Roberto  L7077765    0
    Franck, Travis  C6755437    2
```

After running it, I get an output of my sorted list without any numbers being changed.

```
AZ386   Bill, Gate  I8978999    Taurus  -1
AZ386   Granja, Joao    A4567897    Canis   -1
AZ386   Hadzima, Joseph D3333123    Virgo   -1
AZ386   Homer, Jack U8897529    Virgo   -1
AZ386   Hynes, Tod  T2323111    Taurus  -1
AZ386   Isaacs, William O8796234    Cepheus -1
AZ386   Jackie, Stewart T7773123    Corvus  -1
AZ386   Jay, Jason  F5459908    Draco   -1
AZ386   Kellogg, Suzuki Q1113133    Corona  Founder of Sonny-1
AZ386   Michael, Schumacher U5454231    Aquarius    -1
AZ495   Bent, Bernanke  K8888909    Taurus  Inventor of Hot Money Theory-1
AZ495   Gregory, Nathaniel  P8796543    Eridanus    -1
AZ495   Klein, Janice   Q3773331    Cepheus -1
AZ495   Kogan, Leonid   Q7777077    Capricornus -1
AZ495   Kritzman, Mark  P9090888    Eridanus    -1
AZ495   Little, John    S7878653    Crux    -1
AZ495   Malone, Thomas  A1213878    Scorpius-1
AZ495   Mende, Paul D1219097    Cancer  -1
AZ495   Nachtrieb, Robert   F7878333    Leo -1
AZ495   O'Shea, Rory    Y1212332    Canis   -1
AZ495   Reagans, Ray    X6321235    Canis   -1
AZ495   Roberts, Edward X3434222    Virgo   -1
AZ531   A, Mohd X9878038    Scorpius    -1
AZ531   Ahmed, Faheem   X6836493    Crux    -1
AZ531   Alan, Bovik O5646324    Draco   -1
AZ531   Alexis, Kwasinski   L9875676    Corona  CEO of Koyota Motor-1
AZ531   Babinchuk, Wayne    N9847293    Cancer  -1
AZ531   Barwreck, Obama E6666666    Eridanus    Head of international spy ring-1
AZ531   Cummer, Rick    H3947399    Leo -1
AZ531   Dhanjal, Surinder   C9219437    Canis   -1
AZ531   EL Miligi, Haytham  C3947390    Canis   Green peace activist-1
AZ531   Kwiatkowska, Mila   U3845738    Virgo   -1
AZ531   Lee, Mahnhoon   Q9487400    Taurus  -1
AZ531   Mikhail, Belkin     W9876661    Cepheus -1
AZ531   Misseille, Obama    E6666667    Eridanus    Advisor of Barwreck Obama-1
AZ531   O'Neil, Kevin   L8495849    Virgo   -1
AZ531   Park, Andrew    S4957459    Aquarius    -1
AZ531   Rahman, Musfiq  S8765567    Corvus  -1
AZ531   Sharma, Mridula S7654566    Taurus  Queen of Ingland-1
AZ874   Ackerman, Joshua    P9809777    Virgo   -1
AZ874   Akinc, Bridget  F5456776    Virgo   -1
AZ874   Andrea, Alu T7777656    Taurus  -1
AZ874   Andreas, Gerstlauer P9868568    Cepheus -1
AZ874   Asquith, Paul   F5676655    Aquarius    -1
AZ874   Bei, Yu U8978999    Scorpius    -1
AZ874   Deji, Akinwande S7678769    Canis   -1
AZ874   Francesco, Monticone    D6544678    Eridanus    -1
AZ874   Jeff, Andrews   Q2123443    Cancer  United Nation negotiator-1
AZ874   Sarfraz, Khurshid   I8767890    Leo -1
AZ874   Sarfraz, Khurshid   S5654678    Canis   -1
AZ874   Vijay, Garg     K7686546    Capricornus -1
AZ874   Zheng, Wang     J8767765    Eridanus    -1
AZ874   Zhuoran, Zhao   E6577779    Crux    -1
AZ900   Barnett, Arnold U7678765    Corvus  -1
AZ900   Berndt, Ernst   G5643211    Taurus  -1
AZ900   Carroll, John   G5656789    Cepheus -1
AZ900   Chen, Elaine    Y7876780    Draco   Nobel prize (Beauty)-1
AZ900   Chu, Zen    R2000098    Cepheus -1
AZ900   Costello, Anna  P7878665    Eridanus    -1
AZ900   Cusumano, Michael   E4543409    Eridanus    -1
AZ900   Dougherty, Jim  W1232121    Scorpius    -1
AZ900   Dyer, Barbara   T8888765    Crux    -1
AZ900   Eppinger, Steven    T2343111    Cancer  -1
AZ900   Fernandez, Roberto  L7077765    Leo -1
AZ900   Franck, Travis  C6755437    Canis   IBN chief researcher-1
AZ900   Vijay, Garg R6567123    Corona  -1
AZ900   Zheng, Wang U1321254    Capricornus -1
```

Thank you in advance. I've been trying to fix it all day.

Comment: Start by showing a small reproducible example. We don't want to look at blocks of code or blocks of logs.

Comment: Debug.  Show two values which produce the "wrong" compareTo result.

Comment: Following up on @HotLicks suggestion: If you don't have a debugger, drop a printout or two into the code before the `compareTo()` that's malfunctioning, showing the two values being compared. The problem is almost certainly not the compare but the logic surrounding it.

Comment: There is some basic design issue with this code. why are you playing with strings, why not create a reservation object with desired attributes and then try to compare particular attribute values instead of getting a substring to compare which might break because you do not know exact position where the name starts

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks and Keshlam. I will give that a try. Sanjeev, I tried doing it with objects but I had troubles so I switched to strings which worked a little bit better for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

You have sorted the lines from the beginning of lines (offset 0). You are trying to binary search from offset 6 inside offset 0 sorted data. That will never work! If you are binary searching within the lines from offset 6, you should have sorted the lines from the same offset because the order of lines will be different if you sort from offset 6.

Look at the code block below:

```
//These are STRINGS to get the first name from the flight900 list
String str0 = array[middle].substring(6,9);
String str1 = array[middle].substring(6,10);
String str2 = array[middle].substring(6,11);
String str3 = array[middle].substring(6,12);
String str4 = array[middle].substring(6,13);
```

Looks like it is a horrible way to parse the first name in the list. Just because the names can be of varying length you cannot try to create all possible substrings and compare them! You must parse the line with proper delimiter so that you can cleanly separate out the name for comparing. Then you will not have so many strings to compare!

Recommendation:

Parse the line and create an object out of it. You may put the data in a custom class or even a map with key-value pairs. Basically you should hold the line data in parsed format for using the contents easily.

Then, if you want to search by flight name create a map with the already parsed flight name as the key and the parsed object as the value. Now for looking up any flight you can get the value from the name in the map. If there are going to be more than one flight having same name (probably that is not case, but I don't know your data) then you should hold a list against each flight name to hold multiple flight data objects parsed from each flight line. When you lookup a flight name you will get list of all flights matching that name.

Hope that helps!